# AlmaLinux 8.8 vlan doesn't work after system restart

Tags: vlan

I have created a vlan on AlmaLinux 8.8 using nmtui and it is working.
I could ping other ip in vlan.

After restart ping doesn't work on vlan ip, and linux doesn't answer on any port on vlan ip. On other interfaces everything is ok. Of course there is no errors in logs.

I found that only resolution for this problem is disable end re-enable vlan interface. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide your actual relevant configuration files.

Comment: I think most relevant is ifcfg-enp3s0.101:
VLAN=yes
TYPE=Vlan
PHYSDEV=enp3s0
VLAN_ID=101
REORDER_HDR=yes
GVRP=no
MVRP=no
HWADDR=
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=default
NAME=enp3s0.101
UUID=a209e051-e445-4aae-a7cc-0dc2476da3b4
DEVICE=enp3s0.101
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=172.24.1.2
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=172.24.1.1
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
IPV6_DISABLED=yes

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more information and format it properly. It's unreadable in the comments.